# Linux basic script to print free and total memory

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to teach myself some basic scripting and unable to use the awk command properly.  I want to show the current free and total memory available in MB from the free -m command. However, I keep getting an error that I'll post below.  Why is this?

syswatch:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use free command to show current free and total memory available in MB

free -m | awk `{print "Free/Total Memory : $3 / $1 MB"}`
```

Output / Error:

```
[root@testit /root]# ./syswatch
./syswatch: {print: command not found
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
        awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options:
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
        -v var=val              --assign=var=val
        -m[fr] val
        -W compat               --compat
        -W copyleft             --copyleft
        -W copyright            --copyright
        -W help                 --help
        -W lint                 --lint
        -W lint-old             --lint-old
        -W posix                --posix
        -W re-interval          --re-interval
        -W source=program-text  --source=program-text
        -W traditional          --traditional
        -W usage                --usage
        -W version              --version

To report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info', which
is section `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the
printed version.
```

Expected output:

```
Free/Total Memory : 133/190 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the percentage

```
free -m | sed 1d | awk '{print "Free/Total Memory ", $1, " ", $3 /  $2}'
```

Your problems

- You are using backticks (used to execute a sub shell)
- You are also evaluating the header of the output of `free`: `sed 1d` deletes the first line
- You are dividing the wrong columns: `$1` is the memory type, `$2` is the total and `$3` is the used memory

If the `/` sign is not a division (see your comment) then

```
free -m | sed 1d | awk '{printf "Free/Total Memory %s %s/%sMB\n", $1, $3, $2}'
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to print the total MB. So the output would be " Free/Total Memory : 133/190 MB"

Comment: The total is on the second column and is expressed in MB. If you divide the used memory by the total you have a ratio, wich by definition has no unit.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to print both seperately using the "/" as a way of seperating them such as in the string.

Comment: But then you have to quote it otherwise `awk` will perform a division

Comment: Makes sense, and each string needs to be seperated by a comma?

Comment: Not each string, each parameter for `print`